# wp_get_archives link to that particular archive page

Tags: wordpress

Setup an Archive list on the right of my page and the design has a "view" button after each item.

I'm trying to have that view button link to the archive month page.

Looking at doing something with the after and adding a href="" to the view button, However not sure what to reference to get that to happen.

My current code is as follows :

```
                <?php
                // Get Archives'
                $args = array (
                    'type'  => 'monthly',
                    'order' => 'DESC',
                    'after' => '<div class="pull-right"><a class="view" href="#">View</a></div>',
                    'limit' => '6'
                );
                $archives = wp_get_archives( $args );
                ?>
```

As you can see the 'after' parameter in the array is where I am trying to add the href.

Hope that makes sense.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Few things about [`wp_get_archives`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_archives):

- It doesn't return anything except if you force the `echo` parameter to `0` - otherwise calling the function will result of the archive links to be printed.
- The `after` parameter is dependant of the `format` parameter - it is only used when using the "html" (default - list mode) or "custom" format. What it does is to display the value you pass as parameter ***after*** the link. So you don't need to reference the link inside. Use it in combination with the `before` parameter to achieve what you want to do here.
- You don't really need to set the `type` as `monthly`, as it is the default value for this parameter. Same for the `order` parameter, which default is allready `DESC`.

So a valid call would be:

```
wp_get_archives(array(
    'format' => 'custom',
    'before' => '<div class="pull-right">',
    'after'  => '</div>',
    'limit'  => 6
));
```

You probably notice that it doesn't output exactly what you are trying to do, as it miss the `class` `view` on your links. You need to add a filter on [`get_archives_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_archives_link/) in order to achieve this (this go in your theme *functions.php*):

```
add_filter('get_archives_link', 'get_archive_links_css_class' );
function get_archive_links_css_class($link) {
    return str_replace('href', 'class="view" href', $link);
}
```

This will add the class before the `href` attribute.